# How to distinguish addresses currencies apart on php

Tags: bitcoind, litecoin, address, php, peercoin

I need depending on the address to assign a value of the transaction. 
Both at the level of php distinguish btc ltc from ppc?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you are trying to achieve?

All use different addressing guidelines and their address;s are usually easy to tell apart, aside from that if your writing php to interact with them then you will be using the RPC interface most likely which will need a separate instance for each currency.

Answer (score 1):

- A [Bitcoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address) address always start with `1` or `3`.
- A [Litecoin] address always starts with the letter `L`.
- A [Peercoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peercoin#Addresses) address starts with the letter `P`.

Assuming you can figure out how to check the first character in php, you can distinguish between different addresses. Then you can program whatever value you want into the transaction. Good luck!